# Add All Option To Top of Bound Combobox

Tags: c#, winforms, combobox

I need to add All as a selectable choice to the top of a combobox on winform.  I have tried both of the codes below, which one does not throw an error but the value is not added:

```
public void GetData()
{
  using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(SqlConnection))
  {
    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter("select [empname] from [Testdb].[dbo].[Test] order by [empname] Asc", conn);
    conn.Open();
    da.Fill(ds, "Test");
    cboemployees.Items.Insert(0, "All");
    cboemployees.DisplayMember = "empname";
    cboemployees.DataSource = ds.Tables["Test"];
  }
}
```

Now this syntax throws an error of

> error column 'empname' does not belong to table

```
public void GetData()
{
 using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(SqlConnection))
 {
    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter("select [empname] from [Testdb].[dbo].[Test] order by [empname] Asc", conn);
    conn.Open();
    da.Fill(ds, "Test");
    DataRow row = dt.NewRow();
    row["empname"] = "All";
    dt.Rows.InsertAt(row, -1);
    cboemployees.DataSource = dt;
 }
}
```

What is the proper way of adding a selectable item to the top of a bound combobox?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the row to your table instead.

```
SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter("select [empname] from [Testdb].[dbo].[Test] order by [empname] Asc", conn);
conn.Open();

da.Fill(ds, "Test");

// Add the row for All
var allRow = ds.Tables["Test"].NewRow();
allRow[0] = "All";
ds.Tables["Test"].Rows.InsertAt(allRow, 0);

cboemployees.DisplayMember = "empname";
cboemployees.DataSource = ds.Tables["Test"];
```

Comment: This adds All to the bottom of the list, is there a way to have it be the 1st entry in the list?

Comment: yes use `ds.Tables["Test"].Rows.InsertAt(allRow, 0);`. See my edit with this in it.

Comment: that throws an error of Input array is longer than the number of columns in this table

Comment: Is your query returning any rows? You will receive that error if your table has no columns. That is pretty strange.

Comment: Yes, my query is returning rows.  Your initial post worked, just added the "All" option to the bottom of the list.  Your updated answer throws the error.